# Didn't find class “androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication” on path: DexPathList on lower API <= 19 devices

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, android-multidex

I'm trying to add Multidex [support](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) to my app. But I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip       file "/data/app/com.dfn.partner-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories[/data/app-lib/se.android-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

My gradle have:

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
depenencies {
   ...
   implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
   ...
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml have :

```
<application
  android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
  ... >
...
</application>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: It appears to be looking for the androidx version of the multidex support library. Someone else might be able to give a more complete answer as to what is going wrong here but try changing the mutlidex dependency to the androidx version `androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1`. When you do this you will likely need to update the `android:name` of your application in the manifest to `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication` as well.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I was mistaken in the question, I use `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication` and `'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` in the application and an error appears

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I just tried different options.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53203590/1435985). For your APK can you see if the multidex related classes are also found outside of the primary dex file (classes.dex) using the APK analyzer in Android Studio?

Comment: Did u have used custom application class ??

Comment: @Md.ibrahimkhalil yes

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 19):

I got this error after adding multidex until I cleaned:

`./gradlew clean`

Comment: After I added multidex from androidx I got his error. "Clean Project", then "Syncing project with Gradle files", then run again and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

I cleaned the project:

**Build -> Clean Project**

and then I went to:

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Compile, now should work!

Comment: This worked for me. You need to do them in exactly the same order as written in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For api level < 21, platform uses Dalvik runtime for executing application code. For such cases, multidex library should be a part of the primary DEX file of your app which can then manage access to the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

In your case, looks like Multidex library is not present in the primary dex file and hence during startup, you app is giving you error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

You need to explicitly specify these multidex classes in either multiDexKeepFile or multiDexKeepProguard to mark those as required in primary dex.

**multiDexKeepFile**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-main-dex-list.txt')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Content of multidex-main-dex-list.txt goes as below:

`androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication`

**multiDexKeepProguard**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-main-dex-list.pro')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Content of multidex-main-dex-list.txt goes as below:

`-keep class androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication`

Comment: Oddly enough, I didn't have keep class multidex in prior to migrating to AndroidX libraries but after migrating to AndroidX library I needed to add -keep class androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication to ensure the application runs on pre android 5 devices

Answer (score 1):

if you are using androidx use depedency below

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
}
```

for support library use

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to replace in my build.gradle.kts (module: app):

```
implementation("com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3")
```

with

```
implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
```

and add the following in my gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vector as images, change **android:src** to **app:srcCompat** in your Xml